# My docker-compose is failing with Cannot find config.m4

Tags: docker, docker-compose

i am updating a docker installation from php 7 to 8.2

I am now getting the error when running `docker-compose up -d --build`

```
Status: Downloaded newer image for php:8.2-apache
 ---> c23ae93fd864
Step 2/40 : RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
---> Running in 2aa521a2771a
Cannot find config.m4. 
Make sure that you run '/usr/local/bin/phpize' in the top level source directory of the module
 
ERROR: Service '$DOCKER_USER-service' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c 
docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql' returned a non-zero code: 1
COMPLETE
```

it is failing early on in the Dockerfile

These are the first 3 lines of my Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.2-apache

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
```

`php:8.2-apache` works fine on my macos running docker. it is only failing on an umbutu server running docker

if i use `php:8.0-apache` on the umbutu docker it runs fine, but then my version of laravel requires at least php 8.1. ARG!!!!

Any help on how to proceed/debug would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Could you confirm that `'/usr/local/bin/phpize'` dir contains `config.m4` ?

Comment: Also, does this help; https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/233 ?

Comment: It is mandatory the docker-php-ext-install? I have a Dockerfile ready to use for laravel. Could share the entire Dockerfile?

Comment: @JRichardsz thanks. I found another docker image that appears to work

Comment: I used the 3-line Dockerfile in your question and the problem does not reproduce. What Docker build command did you use? Did you specify any argument or environment variable?

Comment: Which docker version are you running? Your Dockerfile works just fine on v24.0.4!

Comment: i gave up on trying to make the image I was using work, and starting using docker image php:8.1-apache-bullseye and it works great

Comment: Any updates on this? I have the same issue and I need PHP 8.2.0 - But its not working!

Comment: @Mike_NotGuilty, i gave up. I ended up trying a different image to use